# How can I update the database in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, save

I am building a web service and trying to update my db but obviously this is not the right method to do it. Can I have a helping hand here, I have tried all variations. I got this error: local variable 'Printer' referenced before assignment. I tried to change the name to PrinterObj but then I got the error: PrinterObj have no save method. What I want to do is to save to a new record if it is not existing and if it exist I want to update. I thought it should be simple.

```
from .models import Printer

class RequestData(APIView):
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

  def get(self, request):
    Printer = Printer.objects.get(printername = printername)
    if Printer: #UPDATE
        Printer.printername = printername
        Printer.ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        Printer.lastupdate = datetime.now()
        Printer.save()
    else: #CREATE
        b = Printer(
            printername = printername, 
            ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            lastupdate = datetime.now()
        )
        b.save()
```

Comment: you are shadowing your own variable Printer = Printer.objects...

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because you specify `Printer = …`, hence `Printer` is a local variable, and to make matters worse, you used `Printer` at the right part of the expression, so it is used before you assign it.

The solution is to give the *object* a different name than the class. Therefore in Python local variables are often written in lowercase.

It will furthermore error on the fact that `.get()` raises an error if it can not find the object. You can use `.first(..)` or even better, use `update_or_create(..)`:

```
class RequestData(APIView):
  permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

  def get(self, request):
    Printer.objects.update_or_create(
        printername=printername,
        defaults={
            'ip': request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'lastupdate': datetime.now()
        }
    )
    return …
```

You still need to return a HTTP response, for example `JsonResponse({'success': true})`. Furthermore a GET request is *not* supposed to have side effects, so perhaps it is not a good idea to create or update objects with `def get(...)`.

Comment: Thanks this looks better. I am to tired to try now. I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: It works like a dream Thank you for taking the time to learn me the right way. Yes I have a JsonResponse at the bottom.